# excel search engine using vba and filters?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following vba code to filter my rows in excel based on the value in my cell C5

```
Sub DateFilter()
    'hide dialogs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'filter for records that have June 11, 2012 in column 3
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10:AS30").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & "*"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My excel columns look like:

```
A            B          C             
Gold         XXX        Manchester
Silver       TTT        London
Black        ZZZ        Scotland
White        WWW        Wales
```

So if I typed in the word 'Gold' in my cell C5 and ran the macro my rows get filtered and only the following would be showing:

```
Gold        XXX       Manchester
```

However, now I want to be able to filter my rows by putting a value from either column a, b or c into my cell c5 and filter the rows.

So if I enter the letters 'TTT' into cell c5, this will filter my rows like so:

```
Silver       TTT       London
```

And if I type in Wales into cell c5 It filters my rows like:

```
White      WWW    Wales
```

The other thing I want to do is be able to filter my rows based on a multiple search criteria so if I put a combination of a value from column a, b and c in my cell c5 like so:

```
White  WWW Wales
```

Then I end up with the following filtered result:

```
White      WWW       Wales
```

Please can someone show me how I would be able to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you expect Excel or VBA to know which column your text applies to?  Once you figure that out, you'll be well on your way to a solution.  For instance, is column B always three characters?  If so, you could build in some logic to check the length of cell C5 and if it equals 3, you know it applies to column B.  Now you'll get jammed up if someone enters 'Red', but hopefully you can work out some logic on how to handle that (perhaps a list of colors that gets checked first).  really there are a lot of design decisions you need to make before you start coding...that's my $.02 at least.

Comment: Add auxiliary column containing concatenated strings from those columns and separated by spaces. This column will be used for filtering, and you may hide it if you want. Also try different options like replacing all spaces in search string by *, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter for "any" column, you could combine a Find result and Filter like this:

```
Sub DateFilter()
Dim nRow As Range
Dim toSearch As Range
    'hide dialogs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'filter for records that have June 11, 2012 in column 3

    Set toSearch = Range("A1:C4")
    'detect row that matches criteria:
    Set nRow = toSearch.Find(ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value)
    If Not (nRow Is Nothing) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1:A4").AutoFilter Field:=nRow.Column, Criteria1:="*" & nRow.Value & "*"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried this using your values pasted in A1 to C4, with C5 as my search text cell. You will have to adjust these values but apart from that you should be fine.

For your last query, "White  WWW Wales" I would suggest to go with omegastripes' suggestion of an additional concatenated cell somewhere in column AA or so.

Comment: thanks for your code however I could not get this to work for me? it only searches one column not any more than that

Comment: It searches the entire range you define in `toSearch`. There was a different error though: the `Field` property of the `AutoFilter` was not properly set. Edited the code to reflect that.